# Strange characters for _id field when doing mongoose aggregate query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am running a query to try and get a count of duplicate id records.

"song" is a subdocument which contains just an _id field in the database. After I run the query I am getting these strange characters in my console output, how come I am not able to get the actual id string that looks like, "555699e4ab3e43ec12accaf9"?

[image: console]

Comment: Looks like encoding of the binary value within your debugger, remember that the value you reference is the string representation, it isn't the raw representation of the _id

Comment: If you expand the `_id` property in the debugger does it show the correct value? There's an arrow next to the property name, which leads me to believe it can be inspected further.

Comment: No, it just shows the same thing: http://i.imgur.com/TQmjLyp.png

@Sammaye - why is it a binary value? In the database it looks like a normal string.

Comment: Nah, that is just what the mongo console shows, the mongo console automatically decode the binary value to the hex value

Comment: Is there anything I can do to get the debugger to display that value? I thought _id.id was supposed to show this string representation but in the case of this aggregate query it doesn't appear to be working. Am I aggregating a subdocument properly here? First time doing aggregates and it felt very confusing.

Comment: I am not familiar with your debugger. What are you using to do this?

Comment: Also, for verification, try echoing to the node.js console and see if the value works there

Comment: Try `console.log(util.inspect(results))` (be sure to `require` the `util` module)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those characters are the 12 byte id *binary* string. 
And it's actually ***`_id.id`*** i.e. `id` property on the `_id` object which is an [ObjectID](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/4.0.3/lib/schema/objectid.js).
Your 24 byte binary "555.." is `_id` itself, which converts to string automatically if you use it as one.

---

[image]

<sup>* more details on how object can be represented as a string: [Object.prototype.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString)</sup>

Unfortunately for you, whatever IDE you're using is showing it as an object (which is actually what it really is).

Try `console.log(util.inspect(results))` (be sure to `require` the `util` module)

---

In any case, `console.log(result[0]._id)` will give you the 24 byte hex string  "5556...ccaf9".

If you don't want the `_id` which is an object, there's also a getter `id` which is a String by default.

```
console.log(typeof result[0]._id) //=> "object"
console.log(typeof result[0].id) //=> "string"
```

Comment: But as you can see in my screenshot, neither of those options are giving me the result as a 24 byte hex string. How come?

Comment: "like 0 converts to false"? That is because of loose typing, this is because of the objects `__toString` representation. `0` does not actually convert to `false` it is just evaluated as `false` in `boolean` statements.

Comment: @Sammaye Thanks for the correction. I *knew* it was something different from loose typing, just didn't know exactly what it was. Corrected.

Comment: __toString is the PHP edition. I searched around a bit more and the JS edition is just toString https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString